# How to keep components of web page in separate files

Tags: html, navigation

I want to put all of the components of my web page into separate files. For example, I want to just important my Navigationbar.html into the current one so that if I want to edit the navigation bar I do not have to change it on all of the pages I have already made.

Is there a way for me to manage it in a separate file and then to call it so that it appears on my current html page. For example:

```
<body>
<import banner.html>
<import navigationbar.html>
<p>Hello world</p>
</body>
```

Comment: This may be of interest: http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-html-imports/

Comment: @winseybash [html imports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) are a no go, all major vendors have stated they won't be considering it for implementation due to compatibility issue in it's current spec.

Answer (score 0):

An [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) tag may accomplish what you're trying to do:

```html
<iframe src="http://example.com/"></iframe>
<p>Hello, World!</p>
```